# Array from multidimensional JSON

Tags: php, json

I get my JSON from an API, `http://www.dr.dk/mu/programcard?Title=$like("Store danske Videnskabsfolk Niels Bohr")`

When I try to show the resulting array, like this:

```
$url = 'http://www.dr.dk/mu/programcard?Title=$like("Store danske Videnskabsfolk Niels Bohr")';
$req = file_get_contents($url);
$json_a = json_decode($req, true);

print_r($json_a);
```

All I get is

```
Array ( [ResultGenerated] => 2015-02-12T14:01:09.50486Z [ResultProcessingTime] => 1 [Data] => Array ( ) [ResultSize] => 0 [TotalSize] => 0 )
```

The 2 dimension (Data) is empty, and that's where the important info is.
Why is this happening?

Comment: What is the raw JSON you're getting back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to change the spaces to `%20` like this:

```
$url = 'http://www.dr.dk/mu/programcard?Title=$like("Store%20danske%20Videnskabsfolk%20Niels%20Bohr")';
```

Comment: Wow, I'm so stupid, thanks alot :) The name is coming from a filename, so the spaces has to be converted into "%20" in the script, can you help with that?

Comment: @Sims Just use this line after the declaration: `$url = str_replace(" ", "%20", $url);` and it should work fine